# Eilenberg-Mac lane spaces and a generalization

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be two abelian groups and let $n>1, m>1$ be two different integers. How many different spaces $X$ (up to homotopy) do we have with the property $\pi_{n} X=G$ , $\pi_{m} X=H$ and $\pi_{\ast} X=0$ otherwise? is this number finite ?

Comment: One candidate is just the product $K(G,n) \times K(H,m)$, so I guess you are asking for spaces with the desired property that are *not* homotopy equivalent to products of Eilenberg-Maclane spaces.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming $m > n$, there is a method for classifying such spaces using a technique from the Postnikov tower. Namely, such a space has a map $X \to K(G,n)$ inducing an isomorphism on $\pi_n$, and if we convert this into a fibration it has fiber $K(H,m)$.

Such bundles are classified by a "k-invariant": an element in $H^{m+1}(K(G,n) ; H)$. One direction takes such a cohomology class, represents it as a map $K(G,n) \to K(H,m+1)$, and then takes a (homotopy) pullback. To see that this is actually a bijective correspondence requires a little bit of obstruction theory (and uses critically that $n > 1$; otherwise we'd also need to classify an action of $G$ on $H$).

One should note that if you only ask that $\pi_n X$ and $\pi_m X$ are abstractly isomorphic to $G$ and $H$ rather than choosing isomorphisms, the $k$-invariant is only well-defined up to the action of the automorphism groups $Aut(G)$ and $Aut(H)$ on $H^{m+1}(K(G,n); H)$.

If $G$ and $H$ are finitely generated abelian groups and at least one of them is finite, then Serre's work using mod-$\cal C$ theory shows that this cohomology group is finite; however, in general you can certainly have infinitely many distinct isomorphism classes (e.g. there are infinitely many homotopy types with $\pi_2 = \pi_3 = \Bbb Z$, because $H^4 K(\Bbb Z,2) \cong \Bbb Z$).

Answer (score 6):

One way to think about how to distinguish, if not classify, such spaces is by [homotopy operations](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/primary+homotopy+operation). In the same way that cohomology operations are natural transformations between cohomology functors, homotopy operations are natural transformations between homotopy functors. By the Yoneda lemma, natural transformations $\pi_n \to \pi_m$ are in natural bijection with the homotopy group $\pi_m(S^n)$, so elements of the homotopy groups of spheres give unary operations on homotopy.

More generally, the $k$-ary operations on homotopy groups are natural transformations $\pi_{n_1} \times \dots \times \pi_{n_k} \to \pi_m$, and by the Yoneda lemma these are in natural bijection with the homotopy group $\pi_m(S^{n_1} \vee \dots \vee S^{n_k})$. For example, the [Whitehead bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_product) $\pi_n \times \pi_m \to \pi_{n+m-1}$ is a well-known family of binary operations coming from some distinguished homotopy classes of maps $S^{n+m-1} \to S^n \vee S^m$. They make the homotopy groups of a space into a graded Lie algebra (up to a degree shift). All of the homotopy operations together give the homotopy groups of a space the structure of a [$\Pi$-algebra](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Pi-algebra), analogous to but much more complicated than the structure of being a module over the Steenrod algebra.

A product of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces always has trivial homotopy operations, so you can distinguish a space from a product of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces by checking to see whether any of its homotopy operations are trivial. For example, the homotopy operation $\pi_2(S^2) \to \pi_3(S^2)$ given by a generator of $\pi_3(S^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ must be nontrivial since it is the universal example; this shows that the $3$-truncation of $S^2$ is a homotopy type with $\pi_2 \cong \pi_3 \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and all other homotopy groups trivial but which cannot be homotopy equivalent to $B^2 \mathbb{Z} \times B^3 \mathbb{Z}$.

Moreover, it's a classical result that $H^4(B^2 A, B)$, the cohomology group that classifies the $k$-invariant of a space with $\pi_2 \cong A, \pi_3 \cong B$, can be identified with the group of quadratic functions $A \to B$. Given such a $k$-invariant, the corresponding quadratic function turns out to be precisely the homotopy operation $\pi_2 \to \pi_3$. So in this case the classification by $k$-invariants and by homotopy operations agree.

Comment: A bit offtopic, but do you know any good reference for that $H^4$ fact that doesn't boil down to a direct computation with $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$ and $K(\mathbb{Z}/p^n,2)$? Why is it conceptually so?